# How to find the correct version of Substrate that can support the current Frontier pallets

Tags: rust, substrate

I started learning Substrate recently. I'm trying to build a runtime with both BABE and EVM. It seems that the latest version of Frontier pallets should work with those v4.0.0-dev pallets from Substrate. However, when I tried to add those pallets from Frontier to the Substrate node runtime, it complained that one of the pallets needed `sp-core v4.1.0-dev`.

Is there a way to have both BABE and EVM in my Runtime?

thanks

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind as to repost this great question on https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ -- and @NukeManDan over there?
Very happy to assist on our shiny new Substrate (and friends) home for your questions!

We can cross post the answer here we arrive at there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use substrate 4.0.0-dev with frontier master, then i had created this https://github.com/sudipghimire533/frontier-substrate-synced.

Or you can try manually merging the [frontier-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template) & [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/).

The problem is that frontier-node-template uses `frontier` branch of substrate which is stale now.